# How to define the multiplication of nparray whose elements are in new class with __mul__ and __add__

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to override the multiplication of numpy arrays whose elements are instances of defined class with implemented `__mul__` and `__add__`?

For instance

```
import numpy 

class A:
   def __init__(self):
      ...
   
   def __add__(self):
      ...

   def __mul__(self):
      ...
   
   def __repr__(self):
      ...

instance = numpy.array([[A(...), A(...)],[A(...),A(...)]])
instance @ instance
```

But the running result is

> TypeError: ufunc 'matmul' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

I tried `__array_ufunc__` and `__matmul__` to resolve the error but I couldn't find usages to refer.

**EDIT**:
I want to use the method of numpy array for convenience. If it's impossible, then `__matmul__` is enough.

Comment: [relevent](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/), try `__matmul__`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__matmul__